# UI Testing Failure - Failed to receive event delivery confirmation within 30.2s of the original dispatch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I record one screen's UI Activity with xcode 7.3.1 ,when I test this recorded UI Activity on simulator Test function will pass.
But when same function with device I got this error.
I already removed animations from particular that screen.
I used xcode 7.3.1 & iPhone 6 (10.3.2)